# Vimeo Javascript API not working when the iframe is hidden initially

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-browser, vimeo

So my problem is this, I need to show a cover image and the actual video will be hidden. Once somebody clicks on the image, the video will become visible should start playing automatically. My code is here http://jsfiddle.net/Vq8Wr/ . This works fine in Chrome but not in any other browser. Any solution would be appreciated

the code is as follows

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
.hide{
   display:none
}

img{
    width:500px;
}
</style>

<iframe class="hide" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/59372982?api=1" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
<img src="http://allthingsd.com/files/2011/05/clouds-1259.jpg" id="video-cover" >

<script>
  $("#video-cover").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    var f = $('iframe'),
    url = f.attr('src').split('?')[0];
    f.show();
    var data = { method: "play" };
    f[0].contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), url);
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
.hide{
   position : absolute;
   left     : -99999px;
}
```

Comment: It works if you change the left position to `-500px`. Find the magic value that suits your needs I suppose.